# put show action on a profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

  def show

    username = params[:username]

    @user = User.find_by_username(username)
    if @user
      @title = "Profile for #{username}"
      user_id = @user.id

      @albums = Album.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

I have managed to display the index of albums for a given user on their profile page.  Moving to the show action for an album displays the pictures in the given album.  How can I put the show action of the album on the user's profile page?

Comment: Link to the show action, or actually show the album on their profile page?

Comment: I want to actually show the album on the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you set up a partial for showing a single album.

app/views/albums/_display.html.erb

```
<h2><%= h album.name %></h2>
<p><%= h album.description %></p>
```

On the user page, you could display the albums by rendering that partial.

```
<% @albums.each do |album| -%>
  <%= render :partial => "/albums/display", :locals => {:album => album} %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: That does not work.  The show action should show the album's name among other things.  Here is the error:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It was an example. I have no idea what your Albums show action or views look like, because you didn't post them. Show us what you're trying to do, and we can help you better.

The error you posted indicates that you are not populating the @albums variable, despite what your code above shows.

Comment: @albums = Album.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", user_id])

This line in the controller is used to display the index of albums for a given user on their profile page.  So I imagine I need something new in the controller to actually show the album on the profile, like @combined = @user.albums or whatever.

Comment: You are confusing the concept of an action and a view. I would suggest a basic Rails tutorial first, then come back to this. You already have the @albums variable populated, so if you want these on the page, put them there.

Comment: Alright you were right.  I was attempting to call the album name with an instance variable in the partial, thus giving me the undefined method. Thanks